# How to configure Memcached to able to store Cache larger than its default?

Tags: php, apache, caching, yii, memcached

Im using Yii2 as a framework, and start working with cache, what i wanted to do is minimally the transaction to the database by storing about 700.000+ rows from database table cached in Memcached, its about 25mb after its simplified. But i keep getting this error.

> MemcachePool::set(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: SERVER_ERROR object too large for cache\r\n (3)

I tried to configure the Memcached using this command

```
memcached -I 128m
```

But always get this warning, with nothing seems in effect

> WARNING: Setting item max size above 1MB is not recommended! Raising this limit increases the minimum memory requirements and will decrease your memory efficiency.

I tried to restart the services but still got nothing changed.

After the warning memcached seems like hanging, even after a while a should use CTRL+C to continue typing other command. Same happend when i using `memcached --version` nothing showed.

Updating imagePath in regedit to `c:\memcached\memcached.exe" -d runservice -m 2048` also seems to be in effect.

Here is my configurations in YII2 Components

```
'cache' => [
     'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
     'servers' => [
          [
              'host' => '127.0.0.1',
              'port' => '11211'
          ]
     ]
]
```

I'm running Windows 11, XAMPP v7.4.30, PHP 7.4, YII2